# How to use add_pipe to add the YIELD generator to the PIPELINE in spaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am taking a course in Udemy and dealing with one issue which is *how to use add_pipe to add the generator in spaCy?* I guess the instructor used spaCy 2.0 due to two reasons. First, **the add_pipe function requires a string in spaCy 3.0**. Second, SentenceSegmenter is no longer available in **from spacy.pipeline import SentenceSegmenter.** Here is the code which the instructor used (Note: I noted what I changed to adapt the spaCy 3.0.):

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
@Language.component("split_on_newlines")    # I added this line for spaCy 3.0
def split_on_newlines(doc):
    start = 0
    seen_newline = False
    for word in doc:
        if seen_newline:
            yield doc[start:word.i]
            start = word.i
            seen_newline = False
        elif word.text.startswith("\n"):
            seen_newline = True
    yield doc[start:]
nlp.add_pipe("split_on_newlines",before="parser")
doc_doc = nlp(u"This is a sentence. This is another.\n\nThis is a \nthird sentence.")
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\binhd\anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3369, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-15-4ccdfd3ee841>", line 15, in <cell line: 15>
    doc_doc = nlp(u"This is a sentence. This is another.\n\nThis is a \nthird sentence.")
  File "C:\Users\binhd\anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 1022, in __call__
    error_handler(name, proc, [doc], e)
  File "C:\Users\binhd\anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 1617, in raise_error
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\binhd\anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 1017, in __call__
    doc = proc(doc, **component_cfg.get(name, {}))  # type: ignore[call-arg]
TypeError: Argument 'doc' has incorrect type (expected spacy.tokens.doc.Doc, got generator)
```

I realized the problem is the pipeline does not want to add the **generator** to the pipeline since the error said it requires spacy.tokens.doc.Doc. I need help finding a way to add the generator such as **yield** to nlp.pipeline while keeping the split_on_newlines the same since I knew how to work with **return** instead of **yield**. I tried *from spacy.pipeline import Sentencizer,SentenceRecognizer*, but it does not work. I also looked at the Q&A of the course, but there is no help.

Answer (score 0):

In spaCy, a simple component that you add as a single function must be a function that takes and returns a Doc. You can't use a yield statement.

It looks like you're trying to use a component to split one Doc into multiple Docs, but you can't do that - a component must give the same number of Docs it gets.

If you want to add sentence boundaries on newlines you can mark the `is_sent_start` attribute. There is an example of a component that does that [here in the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-simple).